# iOS alert-dialog, where to place "yes" and "no"?

Tags: dialog, prompt

I've read alot of threads here about where to place "Yes" and "No" in a alert-prompt-popup. Alot of the arguments made sense about place the "positive" callback first (Yes / No). But what I've notices on Apple-devices is that they've highlighted per default the choice to the right, in the prompt.

As another argument said, focus to extinguish the button which you want the user to press. See my attached image as example. (The left choice is "Yes", and the right is "No")

I want to put it on the left side, but it seems weird that the choice on the right is the one highlighted, it's like that's the default choice.

What do you all think?[image]

Comment: Why do you want to put in on the left side? And what do you want to place there.. the NO button, or the highlight? I doubt that the right one is ALWAYS highlighted

Comment: I want the user to press "Yes" (The answer to the left in the prompt)

Im developing an Titanium Appcelerator app, and the button placed last in the dialog is always highlighted, just as it's supposed to be an cancel-button.

In my head right now: Is it a better practice to make the highlighted button the "Yes"-button?

Comment: I think it comes down to: What do you prefer the user presses? Highlight that (Apple is not always right). Sorry if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: I want them to press Yes.. But is it more obvious if the yes-button is either highlighted Or placed on the left?

Comment: Put Yes on left (that's good and standard), and highlight that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good argument that placing the default action on the right makes an easier workflow:

http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/

More importantly, I suggest re-labelling the buttons to 'skip' and 'watch', since taken with the caption 'video', this allows the user to process and take action with less effort.

http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-the-ok-button-is-no-longer-okay/

Comment: Spot on with The fi

Comment: Spot on with the first link

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the alert that is being provided to the user. If it is an alert with regards to purchasing and item (i.e. In-App Purchases) usually the "No" is highlighted as to prevent accidental purchases.

However, when it comes to cases such as connecting social accounts or opening a link in safari, "yes" should be highlighted because of the likely event that the user was purposely requesting that end result.

Answer (score 0):

**Install and Use cocopods**. (very easy to learn and use, also mainly used).

1. if it is your first time use cocopods, open terminal and Enter $ sudo gem install cocoapods command in terminal.
2. Open a terminal window, and $ cd into your project directory.
3. Create a Podfile. This can be done by running $ pod init .
4. Open your Podfile.
5. running $ pod install. "Cocopods are successfully installed."

**After cocopods installed**: Use Questionnaire FrameWork. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Radkw.gif)

github link below. follow the Use steps.

https://github.com/James201311/Questionnaire

1. import Questionnaire
2. inherite your controller from QuestionaireController
3. override following three methods: 
   func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView, didClosedAt questionIndex: Int, answers: [Bool], _ closedButton: UIButton), 
   func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView, didFinishedAt questionIndex: Int, answers: [Bool]) 
   func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView) -> [String]
4. present the questionnaire view controller you just created!

**Hope this solved your problem.**

Comment: UX questions are not implementation questions. It's less a question of how do I implement this then how do I solve these design problems.